# TeamCity The repository X has a submodule in the commit 'X' at a path 'X', but has no entry for this path in .gitmodules configuratio

Tags: git, teamcity, git-submodules

I am trying to build a Git project on a MacBuild agent.

This project had, at one time, been working. I changed multiple submodule urls (to point to new Git server), and these issues started cropping up. However, the old urls are still available, and are proxyin' to the new Git server address, so I don't think that is the issue. I have verified that the parent/super project is referencing a commit that exists on the Git server (both old and new urls).

I can check out with SourceTree/git locally on any computer without any issues. So, why would this be an issue on the build server (TeamCity).

```
Build 'MedXStream :: Internal' #1 
Started 'Mon Apr 28 16:27:20 EDT 2014' on 'Pauls-MacBook-Pro' by 'pknopf'
Finished 'Mon Apr 28 16:28:21 EDT 2014' with status 'FAILURE Failed to start build'
TeamCity URL http://192.168.5.180/viewLog.html?buildId=1&buildTypeId=MedXStream_Internal 
TeamCity server version is 8.1.2 (build 29993)

[16:27:20]E: bt1 (1m:01s)
[16:27:20] : TeamCity server version is 8.1.2 (build 29993)
[16:27:20] : Checking for changes (running for 1m:01s)
[16:27:20] : Will collect changes in 1 VCS roots
[16:27:20] : Waiting for completion of current operations for the VCS roots
[16:27:20] : Loading current repository state for VCS root 'MedXStream'
[16:27:20] : Detecting changes in VCS root 'MedXStream' (used in Internal)
[16:27:20] : Agent time zone: America/New_York
[16:27:22] : Agent is running under JRE: 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609
[16:27:22] : Publishing internal artifacts
[16:27:22] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending using WebPublisher
[16:27:22] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending using ArtifactsCachePublisher
[16:27:22] : Clearing temporary directory: /Applications/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp
[16:27:22] : Checkout directory: /Applications/buildAgent/work/646019915a7c9b49
[16:27:22]W: Updating sources: server side checkout (32s)
[16:27:22] :     [Updating sources] Using vcs information from server. Reason: no revision information for buildtype Internal and checkout directory /Applications/buildAgent/work/646019915a7c9b49 on agent
[16:27:21] :     [Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout
[16:27:21] :     [Updating sources] Clean checkout reasons
[16:27:21] :         [Clean checkout reasons] Agent doesn't have any version of the project sources
[16:27:21] :         [Clean checkout reasons] Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[16:27:21] :     [Updating sources] Building and caching clean patch for VCS root: MedXStream
[16:27:53]W:     [Updating sources] Failed to build patch for build #1 {build id=1}, VCS root: "MedXStream" {instance id=3, parent internal id=1, parent id=MedXStream, description: "http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/ios/software.git#refs/heads/master"}, due to error: Patch building failed: jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.MissingSubmoduleEntryException: The repository 'http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/mdx/medxchange.library.git' has a submodule in the commit '985645766910a85451368de894d7a02507e63bed' at a path 'SubModules/MedXChange.MobileDevice', but has no entry for this path in .gitmodules configuration
[16:27:54] :     [Updating sources] Repository sources transferred
[16:27:54]W: Will repeat attempt when server will be available, number of attempts left: 2
[16:28:04]W: Updating sources: server side checkout (4s)
[16:28:03] :     [Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout
[16:28:03] :     [Updating sources] Clean checkout reasons
[16:28:03] :         [Clean checkout reasons] Agent doesn't have any version of the project sources
[16:28:03] :         [Clean checkout reasons] Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[16:28:03] :     [Updating sources] Building and caching clean patch for VCS root: MedXStream
[16:28:07]W:     [Updating sources] Failed to build patch for build #1 {build id=1}, VCS root: "MedXStream" {instance id=3, parent internal id=1, parent id=MedXStream, description: "http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/ios/software.git#refs/heads/master"}, due to error: Patch building failed: jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.MissingSubmoduleEntryException: The repository 'http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/mdx/medxchange.library.git' has a submodule in the commit '985645766910a85451368de894d7a02507e63bed' at a path 'SubModules/MedXChange.MobileDevice', but has no entry for this path in .gitmodules configuration
[16:28:09] :     [Updating sources] Repository sources transferred
[16:28:09]W: Will repeat attempt when server will be available, number of attempts left: 1
[16:28:19]W: Updating sources: server side checkout (4s)
[16:28:17] :     [Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout
[16:28:17] :     [Updating sources] Clean checkout reasons
[16:28:17] :         [Clean checkout reasons] Agent doesn't have any version of the project sources
[16:28:17] :         [Clean checkout reasons] Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[16:28:17] :     [Updating sources] Building and caching clean patch for VCS root: MedXStream
[16:28:21]W:     [Updating sources] Failed to build patch for build #1 {build id=1}, VCS root: "MedXStream" {instance id=3, parent internal id=1, parent id=MedXStream, description: "http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/ios/software.git#refs/heads/master"}, due to error: Patch building failed: jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.MissingSubmoduleEntryException: The repository 'http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/mdx/medxchange.library.git' has a submodule in the commit '985645766910a85451368de894d7a02507e63bed' at a path 'SubModules/MedXChange.MobileDevice', but has no entry for this path in .gitmodules configuration
[16:28:23] :     [Updating sources] Repository sources transferred
[16:28:23]E: Patch is broken, can be found in file: /Applications/buildAgent/temp/globalTmp/temp6909424303578745215patch_1
[16:28:23]E: Failed to build patch for build #1 {build id=1}, VCS root: "MedXStream" {instance id=3, parent internal id=1, parent id=MedXStream, description: "http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/ios/software.git#refs/heads/master"}, due to error: Patch building failed: jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.MissingSubmoduleEntryException: The repository 'http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/mdx/medxchange.library.git' has a submodule in the commit '985645766910a85451368de894d7a02507e63bed' at a path 'SubModules/MedXChange.MobileDevice', but has no entry for this path in .gitmodules configuration
[16:28:23]W: jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl$1: Server was not able to build correct patch, most likely due to VCS errors
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.throwError(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:118)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.checkPatch(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:108)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.copyPatchAndCheck(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:69)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.UpdateSourcesPatcherBase.copyPatchToTempFile(UpdateSourcesPatcherBase.java:71)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.UpdateSourcesFromServer.updateSources(UpdateSourcesFromServer.java:60)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.UpdateSourcesBuildStageBase.doSourceUpdate(UpdateSourcesBuildStageBase.java:91)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.UpdateSourcesBuildStageBase.doRecoverableStage(UpdateSourcesBuildStageBase.java:59)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.RecoverableBuildStage.doLastAttempt(RecoverableBuildStage.java:112)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.RecoverableBuildStage.doBuildStage(RecoverableBuildStage.java:70)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:31)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor.doStages(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunAction.doStages(BuildRunAction.java:70)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunAction.runBuild(BuildRunAction.java:50)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.doActualBuild(BuildAgentImpl.java:265)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.access$100(BuildAgentImpl.java:52)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl$1.run(BuildAgentImpl.java:231)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.UnsuccessfulPatchException: Failed to build patch for build #1 {build id=1}, VCS root: "MedXStream" {instance id=3, parent internal id=1, parent id=MedXStream, description: "http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/ios/software.git#refs/heads/master"}, due to error: Patch building failed: jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.MissingSubmoduleEntryException: The repository 'http://stash.medxchange.com/scm/mdx/medxchange.library.git' has a submodule in the commit '985645766910a85451368de894d7a02507e63bed' at a path 'SubModules/MedXChange.MobileDevice', but has no entry for this path in .gitmodules configuration
    at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.AbstractPatcher$1.fail(AbstractPatcher.java:93)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.LowLevelPatcher.readPatchStream(LowLevelPatcher.java:165)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.LowLevelPatcher.applyPatch(LowLevelPatcher.java:88)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.AbstractPatcher.applyPatch(AbstractPatcher.java:42)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchApplierImpl.applyPatch(PatchApplierImpl.java:18)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.checkPatchInFileIsCompleted(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:88)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.patch.PatchDownloaderImpl.checkPatch(PatchDownloaderImpl.java:98)
    ... 18 more

[16:28:23] : ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildFinishing' value='61048.0']
[16:28:23] : Publishing internal artifacts
[16:28:23] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending using WebPublisher
[16:28:23] :     [Publishing internal artifacts] Sending using ArtifactsCachePublisher
[16:28:23] : Build failed to start. Artifacts will not be published for this build
[16:28:23] : ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:artifactsPublishing' value='48.0']
[16:28:21] : Build finished
```

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Check make sure both the main and the 'sub' repo are using the same form of authentication. i.e. `https` vs `ssh`.